# How is the maven version specified in Spring Boot Starters?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm read the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter) but I don't understand how versionId is set in the dependency. For example the [MongoDB starter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb/pom.xml) specifies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But the `version` tag is missing. How is the version of `mongodb-driver` determined when using these starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related not only to starters, if you have many modules in your project they have different dependencies. As regular practice, there is a parent `pom.xml` with general settings.

If you see a dependency in child maven module like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There is a configured dependency in parent `pom` like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Usually, it's more flexible to configure versions with properties:

```
<properties>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.5</commons-lang3.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

`MongoDb` version is defined in [spring-boot-dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/d8f9aad8d436873719df5e005050df646e99a4c1/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) using [Dependency Management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) mechanism.

```
<properties>
    <mongodb.version>3.8.0-beta2</mongodb.version>
<properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

> Dependency management is a mechanism for centralizing dependency
>   information. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common
>   parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in
>   the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the
>   child POMs.

Answer (score 5):

The versions of the starter atrifacts are managed in the starter parent.  For example, if you have this in your POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Then any boot starter dependency you reference will have version 2.0.2.RELEASE, unless you override the default and provide your own version for some reason.

Comment: Right - so I see how it determines the spring-boot version, but where is the version for `mongodb-driver` defined? Not in the [parent pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/pom.xml).

Comment: @Nic Cottrell it's defined in `spring-boot-dependencies` module. Posted as part of the update to my answer.